# How to count the number of objects in a constructor javascript

Tags: javascript

Im working with javascript and would like to know the number of objects inside of a constructor.

I have this:

```
var EventData = function(ID, Name, StartDate, StartTime, EndDate, EndTime, Location, Notes){
  this.type = "event";
  this.id = ID;
  this.name = Name;
  this.startDate = StartDate;
  this.startTime = StartTime;
  this.endDate = EndDate;
  this.endTime = EndTime;
  this.location = Location;
  this.notes = Notes;
};
EventData.prototype.count = function(){
  return //some code;
};
```

And i want to call something like this:

```
var Start = function(){
  var thisEventData = new EventData(1,"Bill", 1,1,1,1, "Home", "N/A");
  console.log(thisEventData.count());
};
```

Where thisEventData.count() would return 10.

Comment: "Number of objects inside of a constructor" doesn't make a lot of sense. You can count the enumerable properties of an object (regardless of where the properties came from) with `Object.keys(obj).length`.

Comment: Uhm, you mean return 9, right ?

Comment: You don't have to prototype a count function. Is simple as EventData.length

Comment: So it would return `10`, but why would it return `10` ?

Comment: I would need 10 if I was to include prototypes with the count. 8 would give me the number of parameters asked.

Comment: I would guess you wanted `9`, but that's just me ?

Comment: yes, the answer by @dfsq gives 9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most natural way in this case would be to store parameters count in some property (maybe private). I'm not sure why you need this, but, yea, something like this:

```
var EventData = function (ID, Name, StartDate, StartTime, EndDate, EndTime, Location, Notes) {
    this._paramsCount = arguments.length;
    this.type = "event";
    this.id = ID;
    this.name = Name;
    this.startDate = StartDate;
    this.startTime = StartTime;
    this.endDate = EndDate;
    this.endTime = EndTime;
    this.location = Location;
    this.notes = Notes;
};
EventData.prototype.count = function () {
    return this._paramsCount;
};
```

**UPD.** Based on the edited question, look like you want to calculate number of own properties of the instance. In this case you would use convenient [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method which returns an array of property names.

```
EventData.prototype.count = function () {
    return Object.keys(this).length;
};
```

Comment: I was just about to save my answer exactly as yours, so i've deleted it and upvoted since its a pretty good approach :)

Comment: @dfsq i think he Op means the properties present, not the arguments passed.  arguments.length will give 3 if we pass only 3 arguments

Comment: @A.B Hm.. originally it was parameters, I guess. Looks like you are right.

Comment: still needs confirmation @dfsq may b this is the scenario, +1 fro edit

Answer (score 4):

Just get the properties of the `EventData` object as an array with `Object.keys`, and then the length of the array?

```
EventData.prototype.count = function(){
  return Object.keys(this).length;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know the number of canonical parameters, use the [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property, in your case:

```
EventData.length
```

or

```
thisEventData.constructor.length
```

Note that it won't count additional parameters (variable arguments) since it infers the count from the constructor object.

If you want to know the property count of the constructed object, use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
Object.keys(thisEventData).length
```

This will give you the count of the *own* properties (excluding the prototype chain).

Or just write your own customizable logic if you need something else, for instance if you want *non-falsey* objects:

```
function getPropertyCount(obj, withPrototypeChain) {
    var prop;
    var count = 0;

    for (prop in obj) {
        if ((withPrototypeChain || obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) && obj[prop])
            ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To build a bit on the accepted answer:

```
export class Person {
      constructor (name, age) {
        if (arguments.length !== 2) {
          throw new Error('invalid Person argument count')
        }
        this.name = name
        this.age = age 
      }
    }
```